# ModColorFix for Chat

Tags: script, chat

Just a very very simple userscript that changes the moderator usernames in chat from blue to green.

Requested by and built for @doppelgreener on becoming a mod.

[image: dopplegreener]

[Link to Github Repo](https://github.com/CalvT/ModColorFix/blob/master/modcolorfix.user.js)

[Link to install](https://github.com/CalvT/ModColorFix/raw/master/modcolorfix.user.js)

Any problems, ideas, etc, drop me a line here or at Github, and I'll see what I can do :)

Comment: I officially endorse this properly-colored userscript.